Law of Total Probability and Conditional Probability
There is something that's a bit confusing for me in the topic of Conditional Probabilities.
Assume we have the Universal Set, which is partitioned into $F$ and $F^c$.
Now if we want to calculate the Probability of $E$ happening; The total rule of probability says that $$Pr(E) = Pr(EF) + Pr(EF^c) = Pr(E|F)·Pr(F) + Pr(E|F^c)·Pr(F^c),$$ which sounds pretty reasonable.
But from another point of view, we can say that Probability of E happening equals = E happens given F has already happened + E happens given F has not happened. Why this argument doesn't lead us to the right answer?

How does that differ from what you wrote?

@lulu My argument is just $Pr(E) = Pr(E|F) + Pr(E|F^c)$

But that's wrong.  Suppose $E$ is certain when $F$ occurs and that $E$ has a $\frac 12$ chance of happening when $F$ does not occur.  Then you are saying that $P(E)=1+\frac 12>1$.  Conditional probability doesn't mean what you think it means.

@VacationDue20000 Your argument would prove that $1=1+1$: just let $E$ be the whole whole space and $F$ any event with probability not $0$ or $1$.

This is essentially about interpreting English phrases of the form “X given Y”; there's a strong tendency in natural language to interpret a statement of assumptions as implying that they're absolutes rather than contingencies.

Consider an extreme example. You are about to enter a boxing match against Mike Tyson in his prime.
Let $E$ be the event that you win the boxing match.
Let $F$ be the event that Mike Tyson has some sort of medical emergency during the match which prevents him from winning.
You are saying, why is not true that $P(E)=P(E\mid F)+ P(E\mid \neg F)$? Well, if Mike Tyson has a medical emergency, you will probably win by default, so $P(E\mid F)=0.9$, say. Given there is no medical emergency, you have basically no chance of winning, so $P(E\mid \neg F)=0$. If probabilities worked the way you suggested, that would mean the probability you best Mike Tyson was $P(E)=0.9+0=0.9$. This is clearly wrong.
Basically, it is worthless to consider conditional probabilities given nearly impossible events. If you had done the calculation correctly, we would need to factor in $P(F)$, the probability of Tyson having a medical emergency, which itself is close to zero. This would have ensured that our calculated $P(E)$ value is small, as it should be.

You are forgetting to "weight" the conditional probabilities $P (E | F), P (E | F^c)$ by their respective priors. In particular, we have that $P (E \cap F) = P (E | F) \color{red}{P (F)}$ and $P (E \cap F^c) = P (E | F^c) \color{red}{P (F^c)}$.
It is obviously not true in general that $P (E \cap F) = P (E | F)$. The left side is the probability that both $E$ and $F$ occur. The right side is the probability that, given $F$ occurs, $E$ also occurs.
As an example, suppose we flip two fair coins. Let $E$ be the event that the first coin lands heads, and let $F$ the event that the second coin lands heads. Clearly, $P (E) = P (F) = \frac{1}{2}$. Since the two flips are independent, we have that $P (E | F) = P (E) = \frac{1}{2}$. And we know that the probability of getting both heads is $P (E \cap F) = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{4} \ne \frac{1}{2}$.
